# Word for a person who likes suffering due to the relief after it

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word to describe the kind of person who likes suffering or pain due to the relief that comes after it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest word that I can think of is *masochist*.

> [masochist](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/masochist)
>
> 1. *Psychiatry.* a person who has masochism, the condition in which sexual or other gratification depends on one's suffering physical pain or humiliation.
> 2. a person who is gratified by pain, degradation, etc., that is self-imposed or imposed by others.
> 3. a person who finds pleasure in self-denial, submissiveness, etc.

Generally speaking, a masochist gets some kind of pleasure from experiencing pain.